# Writing to a x86 MSR register from userland

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have an embedded system running Linux where I need to write to a specific MSR register at boot time, in order to fix a hardware issue.

Writing a kernel module is an obvious option, however there are several kernel versions around (all of them 2.6.xx) and the insmod/modprobe utils in the system do not have support for the -f flag. Thus I would need to compile and distribute a bunch of versions of the module, even when they are not using any kernel API. I would like to avoid this if possible.

Are there any options I may be overlooking?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[msrtool](http://www.coreboot.org/Msrtool) reads MSRs via `/dev/cpu/%d/msr`; as documented in [`man 4 msr`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/msr.4.html), the same path can be used to write them too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However the MSR device was not compiled in (so there is no /dev/cpu/0/msr on this machine)...

Comment: @Grodriguez, usually it's a loadable module called `msr` but not autoloaded.  Is that not available?

Comment: Not in the target system, which means I woudl need to distribute several versions of the module -- same problem I was trying to avoid in the first place..

Comment: I think you're stuck, @Grodriguez.  The `rdmsr`/`wrmsr` instructions are only available at privilege level 0.

Comment: You seem to be right. I guess I have no option but distributing several versions of the module code.